# How would I unit test URLConnection functionality

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030146/sending-sms-through-low-end-api) question here about sending request via SMS API.

But I want to unit test here using JUnit? How do I go about this effectively? I am very new to JUnit and completely clueless.

Any help in getting me started will be thoroughly appreciated

Comment: You have to specify some example of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples of mocking HttpURLConnection with Mockito:

https://gist.github.com/leviwilson/3623053
[Issues with Mocking HttpURLConnection using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599934/issues-with-mocking-httpurlconnection-using-mockito)

Remember that for unit testing, you want to mock anything that goes over the network, makes a database call, etc.

If you had no internet access at all, the tests should still work.

Also don't worry about unit testing third-party libraries. If you want to test a message actually going out over HTTP, then you want to do integration testing.

Comment: Why do you need a dependency on Robolectric?

Answer (score 1):

Use a mock.

Mockito is a good mock library.

Comment: Why not use MockWebServer?